# Complete record of travels

Tags: air-travel

Can I obtain/purchase a record of every trip I have ever made? Dates, country, place/city of entry, etc? I would love to have an accurate record of all my travels.

Comment: Personally I am glad there is no such database, there is already too much personal data stored and subject to hacking, no need to have all my vacation data accessible as well.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, there is no global authority for this kind of thing.  There are third-party services like [TripIt](http://tripit.com) and [OpenFlights.org](http://openflights.org) that let you construct logs of your own travels, but you'll need to punch in your own flights or at the very least forward your airline confirmations etc for processing.

However, many countries offer some form of travel records for entries to/from that particular country: for example, [here is the CBP request form](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) for US travel history.  Note that they don't record where you came from or where you went to, so you'll have to reconstruct that on your own.